# Show a (discrete) colorbar next to a plot as a legend for the (automatically chosen) line colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, legend, colorbar

I tried to make a plot showing many lines, but it is hard to tell them apart. They have different colors, but I would like to make it easy to show which line is which.  A normal legend does not really work so well, since I have more than 10 lines.

The lines follow a logical sequence. I would like to (1) have their color automatically chosen from a colormaps (preferably one that has a smooth ordering, such as viridis or a rainbow).   Then I would like (2) to have the tick marks next to the color bar to correspond to the index `i` for each line (or better a text label from an array of strings `textlabels[i]`).

Here's a minimal piece of code (with some gaps where I am not sure what to use). I hope this illustrates what I am trying.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Genereate some values to plot on the x-axis
x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)

# Some code to select a (discrete version of) a rainbow/viridis color map
...

# Loop over lines that should appear in the plot
for i in range(0,9):
    # Plot something (using straight lines with different slope as example)
    plt.plot(i*x)


# Some code to plot a discrete color bar next 
# to the plot with ticks showing the value of i   
...
```

I currently have this. I would like the color bar to have the ticks with values of `i`, i.e. 0, 1, 2, ... next to it as tick marks.
[Example figure of what I have now.  It is hard to tell the lines apart now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2oxm.png)

Comment: Found some partial hints [through this link](https://tonysyu.github.io/line-color-cycling.html#.WlvI-VQ-dE4), which discusses how to control line color cycling, but I have not figured out yet how to solve my full question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One gets a colormap via `plt.get_cmap("name of cmap", number_of_colors)`.
This colormap can be used to compute the colors for the plots. It can also be used to generate a colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

n = 10 # how many lines to draw or number of discrete color levels

x = np.linspace(0,1,17)

cmap = plt.get_cmap("viridis", n)

for i in range(0,n):
    plt.plot(i*x, color=cmap(i))

norm= matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(0,n+1)-0.5, n)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.arange(0,n))
plt.show()
```

[image]