# How to convert list of integers to colors on a spectrum and display legend or color spectrum pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert a list of integers to be plotted as the color of points in my scatterplot. I realized that I can use a colormap, which does work well in displaying the high values in the range but I don't know how to create a legend to give me an idea of the numerical values they correspond to. I'm trying to create a function that will create this plot and it is based on real data and the values I'm expecting will sometimes range from 0 to 10 or could sometimes be from 500 to 1000, so I would like to have that displayed with some sort of legend color spectrum.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

list_integers = range(0,100) #the range and variance of this list will vary 
x = range(0,100) 
y = range(0,100)
plt.scatter(x, y, color = cm.rainbow(np.array(list_integers)/np.mean(list_integers)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own [legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

list_integers = range(0,100) #the range and variance of this list will vary 
x = range(0,100) 
y = range(0,100)

cmap=cm.rainbow(np.array(list_integers)/np.mean(list_integers))

custom_lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=cmap[i], lw=2) for i in range(len(x))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, color=cmap)
ax.legend(custom_lines, [str(s) for s in x], ncol=5,bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))
```

[image]

EDIT:
If you want to create your own colour bar, then you can do it using the knowledge I mentioned in my comments (sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094288/convert-list-of-rgb-codes-to-matplotlib-colormap), [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253810/show-a-discrete-colorbar-next-to-a-plot-as-a-legend-for-the-automatically-cho), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360879/create-a-discrete-colorbar-in-matplotlib)) and [`ListedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.colors

import numpy as np

list_integers = range(0,100) #the range and variance of this list will vary 
x = range(0,100) 
y = range(0,100)

# create rgb value mapping
cmap=cm.rainbow(np.array(list_integers)/np.mean(list_integers))
# create cmap
my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cmap, name='my_colormap')
# create norm 
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(x, len(x)) 

# create lines for the legend
custom_lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=cmap[i], lw=2) for i in range(len(x))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=cmap, norm=norm)
ax.legend(custom_lines, [str(s) for s in x], ncol=5,bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1.05))

# create the colourbar
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.arange(0,len(x),10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, is there anyway to make the legend a spectrum rather than individual points?

Comment: Like [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar)? I thought based on your question that you want discrete values.
If yes, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253810/show-a-discrete-colorbar-next-to-a-plot-as-a-legend-for-the-automatically-cho or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360879/create-a-discrete-colorbar-in-matplotlib